# I Enabled MFA for my particular Azure Apps. User who login 1st time with Azure , for those user MFA enable. How to enable MFA for all existing user?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I Enabled MFA ( multi-factor authentication ) for my particular  Azure  Apps. User who login 1st time with Azure ,  for those  user MFA enable. How to enable  MFA( multi-factor authentication ) for all existing user. Please Guide me.

If I enabled  MFA from back-end for some users , those user get MFA( multi-factor authentication ) prompt

> Is there any process to enable MFA ( multi-factor authentication ) for all user from Azure Back End

[image]

Comment: Do you have a chance to look into my answer? If it is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Use the "bulk update" button to download a sample file and fill in all the users information into it. (You could export all the users information first and handle it locally)

Then upload the file to update the MFA( multi-factor authentication) configuration.

If you just want to enable MFA for particular Azure Apps, you should use [Azure AD conditional access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/app-based-mfa).

[image]